# WebBrowser Control basic auth title

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, webbrowser-control

I have a WPF app that uses a `WebBrowser` control to load a webpage that performs authentication using a basic auth flow, which is displayed as:

[image]

I want to change what is displayed as the title (BasicAuthName.exe) in the auth prompt, which appears to be based on the filename of the executable hosting the WebBrowser control.

How can this be set at runtime to display a more user friendly title?

Comment: I doubt it's possible easily as this window is provided by lower layers, the credential manager system in Windows - not the webbrowser control itself - which your are not supposed to mess with (plus it can change depending on Windows version and how Windows is installed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. The displayed name is managed by **Windows Security** to inform the user which application is requesting his credentials. The most you can do is change the name of the application itself. If you are using Visual Studio:

1. Open the Project Properties in Visual Studio (right click on project
   in Solution Explorer and select "Properties" from popup menu);
2. On the "Application" tab of the properties window, change the "Assembly name".